# Why ProcessPoolExecutor working serially?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import os
import time

def parInnerLoop(item):
    print(f'Processing {os.getpid()} started on {item}')
    time.sleep(3)
    print(f'Processing {os.getpid()} done on {item}')

def main():
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)

    for itemNo in range(10):
        executor.submit(parInnerLoop(itemNo))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I'm trying to achieve is parallel `for` loop, similar to MatLab, e.g.:

```
parfor itemNo = 0:9
    parInnerLoop(itemNo);
end
```

What I'm getting: all `os.getpid` are same, and execution occurs serially. Any help?

Windows, VSCodium/VSCode, Python 3.7.3

Comment: You are using it wrongly. You are supposed to give the function as argument to `submit()`, not call the function.

Comment: @KlausD. oops, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Klaus, need to change from `executor.submit(parInnerLoop(itemNo))` to `executor.submit(parInnerLoop, itemNo)`.